# Leave just one space between words after applying regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string like this:

`"{{contentious label|Pseudoscience}}This category  is..."`

I need to have a string without special characters:

```
cleanedStr = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z ]+?)', "", string)
```

The problem is that the result is coming like this:

```
contentious labelPseudoscienceThis category   is
```

and I need like the result with just **one space** between words because I will separate each word by empty spaces to tokenize after

```
contentious label Pseudoscience This category is
```

I have already tried a regex that left just one space but I couldn't make it.

Comment: Your input string and pattern/replacement are out of sync: what is the real input/pattern?

Comment: Make your replacement a space character, then use `.strip()` to remove whitespace on the ends, remove lazy quantifier: `re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]+', " ", string).strip()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fixed to let it more clear

Comment: Ah, so you need `re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', string).strip()`

Comment: Two steps. 1) Replace all non-letters with spaces. 2) Replace multiple consecutive spaces `\s{2,}` with a single space. (Beware that `\s` includes `\n` and a couple of others, you might want to use `[ ]{2,}` explicitly.)

Comment: @Tomalak Why two regex steps? `/[^a-z]+/gmi`, replace with a single space, and trim the result.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Because your suggestion does not work with things like `'foo: bar'`, where it would leave two spaces in the middle of the string.

Comment: @Tomalak You sure about that? https://regex101.com/r/g5SAmO/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus D'oh. Of course. :)

Comment: @Tomalak No worries. However the note about newlines could be valid so anything that OP doesn't want stripped should be included in that negated set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may solve the problem using

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', text).strip()
```

Here, you replace whole chunks of 1+ non-letters with a single space, and then `strip()` removes leading/trailing spaces from the result.

Or

```
" ".join(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', text))
```

Here, `re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', text)` returns a list of all chunks of 1+ ASCII letters and `" ".join(...)` joins these list items into a single-space separated string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex, using `str.split()` to split on whitespace, and `' '.join()` to reinsert exactly one space wherever anything was deleted.:

```
cleanedStr = ' '.join(string.split())
```

If you must use regex, then you can use `re.sub` with a matched group, looking for "at least one space" and replacing it with "exactly one space":

```
import re
cleanedStr = re.sub(r'( +)', ' ', x)
```

I would advise doing the entire process in separate steps - remove the "special characters" first, without touching the spaces, and then remove the spaces after that using a separate regex. Using them together is complicated:

```
import re
cleanedStr = re.sub(r'( +)', ' ',  # 2 - replace multiple spaces with single space
                 re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z ]+?)', " ", string)  # 1 - replace with space instead of nothing
             ).strip()  # 3 - remove whitespace from front and back
# produces 'contentious label Pseudoscience This category is'
```